# Float multiple <button> elements in the same direction, with correct order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a group of buttons:

```
<div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg clearButton" onclick="resetSignature();"> Reset </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg skipButton" onclick="skipQuestion();">Skip Question</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg nextQuestionButton" onclick="goToNextQuestion();"> Next Question &rarr; </button>
        </div>
```

(I am using bootstrap). And I have some css:

```
.nextQuestionButton, .skipButton {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    width: auto;
    font-size:16px;
}    
.clearButton {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .clearButton, .skipButton, .nextQuestionButton {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

This generates output like so:
[image]

---

My problem is that I want the green button to be the farthest to the right on a wide screen, and the bottom button on a narrow screen. I tried re-ordering the buttons (among other things), but then it ruined the order on narrow screens. How can I get the green button to line up on the right of the yellow one?
EDIT: Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WookieCoder/3vjeef5a/)

Comment: could you please make a fiddle and share it with us..It would be really helpfull

Comment: Float both orange buttons to the left, and green one right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onrbggL8/1/)

I've changed your HTML a little bit

```
<div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg clearButton" onclick="resetSignature();">Reset</button>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg skipButton" onclick="skipQuestion();">Skip Question</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg nextQuestionButton" onclick="goToNextQuestion();">Next Question &rarr;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your CSS as

```
.nextQuestionButton, .skipButton {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    width: auto;
    font-size:16px;
}
.clearButton {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .clearButton, .skipButton, .nextQuestionButton {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

What I have done is that, i enclosed two of your buttons in a div which is floated right instead of the buttons. To float right the div, I used the bootstrap class `pull-right`.

**UPDATE**

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onrbggL8/2/)

Comment: THANK YOU I had no idea that class even existed, and I looked at bootstrap pretty in-depth (or so I thought)

Answer (score 0):

```
.green {
   float:left; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
   .green {float:right;}
}
```

just float it in different collection when screen is small.